# How do I install the newest Linux kernel (6.5 currently) on Linux Mint (21.2 Victoria currently)

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, linux-kernel

I know how to use `Mainline`, and can install that kernel, but the headers require a newer libc (>= 2.38) than what’s installed (2.35-0ubuntu3.1), and I need the headers to build two modules (zenpower and 8188eu) with dkms, for the system to keep doing what it does.

So of course I need to install that version of libc in a different “slot”, in Gentoo parlance. To be available to those dkms builds. Possibly a whole toolchain.

But I don’t know how that’s done on Mint/Ubuntu/Debian.

I’ve seen it done before, and am not sure if I myself did it before. (I think I installed a separate gcc once to solve this.)
Unfortunately, all my searches fail to find anything of what I might have found previously. Casting doubt to that. I guess I’d lose a game of Family Feud right now. ;)

In any case, I don’t care how complicated it gets, and what system facilities I have to rip up. It is definitely possible. (My phone runs custom hybrid OS of Android, Gentoo, and my own Haskell code, so you can imagine that I do that sort of stuff for fun. :)

Answer (score 0):

Due to the build image update I don't think the mainline kernel works for 6.5+. However You can use apt to install

```
sudo apt install linux-oem-22.04d
```

I guess it might be based on kernel v6.5.0. If you need the latest version then you may need to clone the repo and build it yourself (I built the kernel myself). You may find the `build.sh` file in [focal-mainline-builder](https://github.com/TuxInvader/focal-mainline-builder) useful.